# Formula Field Issue

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist Countries__c in that values
United States US,
United Kingdom UK,
India IN these are the picklist values.
Now My Scenario is I want to select United Kingdom UK it will be populated as UK in another Formula field.

Thanks in advance.

Can you Please Tell me how to make formula for this...?

Comment: can you leverage OOB SFDC State and Country picklists?

Answer (score 1):

When using a picklist in a formula that will eventually resolve to multiple values, use CASE, which is very efficient and designed for the exact task you're looking for:

```
Case(Country__c, "United States US", "US", "United Kingdom UK", "UK", "International")
```

Check out the [Help & Training](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&siteLang=en_US#CASE) reference for the CASE formula.

Answer (score 1):

As your code will always be of 2 Character and placed in most right side this will work for you:

`RIGHT(TEXT(Countries__c), 2)`
[image]

Comment: This has the benefit of working no matter how many countries you have in your picklist, without having to list them in the formula.